# Latest Items created in SPS2013 dont show in Search

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, crawl

Environment: SharePoint 2013

I`ve restarted the Search Crawl and currently the crawl has 4 hours incremental search and full search every night.
Still cant find latest items been added, if searched after more than an hour.

Search Service Application screenshot

- Image link:

[image: screenshot]

- Detailed Search settings Screenshot -

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your screenshots, your last full crawl took 335 hours, which are about 14 days. That means that when making changes you have to wait about 14 days to be able to search them. Once a crawl started it will run till it finishes, which means that your Incremental Crawls won't even start because the content source is still occupied by a full crawl. Your current crawl is running for 4 hours now and it probably will also take 14 days to finish.

Regarding your crawling schedule, you should rethink making a full crawl every night (as a reference, we are doing a full crawl once a month and an incremental crawl every 30 minutes). [Here you](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2013/02/18/sharepoint-20102013-search-incremental-crawl-vs-full-crawl/) can find the difference what's happening when doing a full crawl and when doing a incremental crawl

My suggestion for your current case is, that you stop the Full Crawl and manually start an incremental crawl and take a look how long this will take. Furthermore check your site applications for huge lists (also workflow lists) that may be responsible for the 2 weeks full crawl.

Comment: I`ve started a fresh full crawl on 08th June and its still going on. Wondering how much time it takes to complete the full crawl?

Once completed, planning to start with Incremental search every 2 hours.

Comment: Have you checked before starting the full crawl, if one of your site collections contains a huge list (in term of items)?

Comment: It does contains lots of documents and multiple list. Wondering how can I assess if any list that is huge. From SPD 2013 It show all the possible list, but not sure how to term a list as huge list.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. I mean lists containing over 500k items, so something out of the ordinary. Furthermore two more questions: 1. Which CU do you have installed? 2. How does your Search topology looks like? Do you have a search only server?

Comment: 1. Will update on the CU soon.
2. no seperate search only server

Comment: any clue how much does usually a full crawl will take to complete with no large lists?

Comment: For a content database around 50GB, it made the experience that it'll take 8-10 hours to complete the full crawl. Have you made any progress in your case?

Comment: Full crawl is going on from past 158hours with database size of 2gb max.

Comment: In your Search Administration, can you check the Crawl Log of your Content Source. Are there any warning/errors, is he still doing anything? Also maybe one basic question, how high is your CPU utilization?

Comment: update - I had created 2 new content source search so the 2 sharepoint site are part of separate content source in order to isolate as which is taking time. please check the screenshot. 

http://imgur.com/OPBZDEm

Currently 

a) started Full Crawls for the first "Local SHarePoint Sites" and its been close to 17 hours and still crawling (database size : 1.5GB)

b) Not started with Mysites.

c) Restarted IIS & Search service.

Wondering what more shall I do to get this working. Kindly assist

Comment: Check finer details of Local SharePoint Sites settings - http://imgur.com/5MgrcDo, may be something u can find its not right.